# What is the volume of the flying saucer?

Tags: calculus, integration, solid-of-revolution

> What is the volume of the flying saucer that comes from rotating $y=\sin x\;(0\le x\le\pi)$ around the $y$ axis?

Here is a diagram for visualization aid:
[image: slice of flying saucer]
We will work with horizontal circular slices, so we have
$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1\pi x^2\,dy&=\int_0^1\pi\left(\sin^{-1} y\right)^2\,dy\\
&=\pi\left(y\left(\sin^{-1}y\right)^2+2\sin^{-1}y\sqrt{1-y^2}-2y\right)\biggr|_0^1\\
&=\frac{\pi^3}4-2\pi
\end{align}$$

However, the answer key says $V=\int_0^\pi2\pi x\sin x\,dx=2\pi^2$. Where was I wrong?

Comment: your solution is true. but What's this $V=\int_0^\pi2\pi x\sin x\,dx=2\pi^2$.

Comment: @MyGlasses It is the answer key at the back of the book. I have been wondering where that $2\pi x\sin x$ came from.

Comment: It may be the surface or other thing. let I see my book.

Comment: If you rotate a curve around an axis you get a surface, hence the answer to your actual problem is zero. To get a positive volume, you need to rotate a *region* around an axis. So, is the region $\{0\leq x\leq \pi, 0\leq y\leq \sin(x)\}$ or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out why the answer could be $\int_0^\pi2\pi x\sin x\,dx=2\pi^2$. The flying saucer can be visualized by looking at the following longitudinal section:
[image: Longitudinal section of flying saucer]
By using cylindrical shells, we have $V=\int_a^b2\pi xh\,dx$, where $a=0$, $b=\pi$ and $h=\sin x$. This leads us to the answer in the key $\int_0^\pi2\pi x\sin x\,dx=2\pi\cdot\pi=2\pi^2$.

Answer (score 0):

I get frustrated if it comes to integrating inverses of trig functions. So I tried something simpler. Take a look at the following figure:

[image]

The volume of the red hollow cylinder of inner radius $r$, of outer radius $r+\Delta r$, and of height of $\sin(r)$ is

$$\pi((r+\Delta r)^2-r^2)\sin(r)=\pi(2r\Delta r\sin(r)+\Delta^2 r\sin(r)).$$

So, the total volume of the "negative" of the flying saucer is

$$2\pi\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2}r\sin(r)\ dr=2\pi.$$

The volume of the cylinder of radius $\frac{\pi}2$ and height $1$ is

$$\frac{\ \pi^3}4.$$

So the volume is the flying soucer is

$$\frac{\ \pi^3}4-2\pi.$$